# Windows 11 quieting audio while in any voice call

Tags: audio, windows-11, bluetooth

While in any voice call, discord especially, any other audio is severely muted. I have gone into the windows communications settings and turned it off, I have gone into Discord settings and made sure those are right, I have turned off spatial sound, I have updated my drivers and systems. nothing seems to work. I've been having these problems since I got this laptop a year ago and I haven't found a solution.
only happening with bluetooth for some ungodly reason.
I may have previously solved it, but i have since forgotten and i had to reset my laptop. So who knows?